# Create a callable component from react-responsive

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to create a callable component to check if device is mobile or desktop

```
import { useMediaQuery } from 'react-responsive'

const CheckDeviceScreen = () => {
  return useMediaQuery({
    query: '(min-device-width: 1224px)'
  })
}

export default CheckDeviceScreen;
```

Then I'm passing that props to a Route

```
import CheckDeviceScreen from "./Others/CheckDeviceScreen";

<Route exact path="/"> <Home isDesktop = {<CheckDeviceScreen/>}/></Route>
```

then in my Home page

```
const Home = ({isMobile}) => (
  {!isMobile && 
    //display something
  }
)
```

But isMobile always return true even I'm viewing it at different device. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

What you created is not called a "callable component" but simply just a function. Because react components should return JSX.

Keeping that in mind, then in your code should be

```
import CheckDeviceScreen from "./Others/CheckDeviceScreen";

<Route exact path="/"> <Home isDesktop = {CheckDeviceScreen()}/></Route>
```

---

if you tried `console.log(<CheckDeviceScreen />)` vs `console.log(CheckDeviceScreen())` you will find that the first returns an object which will always have a `true` condition when checked with `!isMobile`. But the other `console.log` will return the returned calling of the function, which is the check condition that you want: `true` or `false`

Comment: the problem when I call CheckDeviceScreen() I got an error 
Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app

Comment: @Newboy11 . Fixed the code. The problem is: you shouldn't call the function when passing it as a parameter, instead you just reference and it will get called when the component renders

Comment: Check this [sand box](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-bas-l7fup?file=/src/App.js) for a working code example. calling the function is only valid when you debug using `console.log(CheckDeviceScreen())`. otherwise, you just need to pass it without the parentheses like this `isDesktop = {CheckDeviceScreen}`

Comment: I still have to use isMobile (). If I use isMobile its not working
export default function Home({ isMobile }) {
  return (
    <div>
      {!isMobile() && <div>Hello Not Mobile</div>}
      {isMobile() && <div>Hello Mobile</div>}
    </div>
  );
}

Comment: Scratch what I said before about not calling the function when passing it, I was thinking about something else. You should be able to use `isMobile={CheckDeviceScreen()}` with no problem, I tried it [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-bas-l7fup?file=/src/App.js:287-317)

Comment: I don't know why I'm having a problem using isMobile={CheckDeviceScreen()}. Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:

Comment: Don't know why you are getting that error. I even ran it on my computer -not in a sandbox- and still got it to work

Comment: Did you call it inside ReactDom.render?
ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
    <div>
      <Route exact path="/"> <Home isDesktop = {CheckDeviceScreen()}/></Route>
    </div>
  </Router>
document.getElementById("root")
);

Comment: your last example has error https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-bas-l7fup?file=/src/App.js

Comment: No, you can't call it in the `index.js` file where you call `ReactDom.render`. `ReactDom.render` should only just receive components with no props added to them, as `<React.StrictMode><App /></React.StrictMode>` then you add the component with the props you want in the `App` component

Comment: I tried to call it inside ReactDom.render and it threw the error that you are experiencing. please follow the structure as in the [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/gifted-bas-l7fup?file=/src/index.js:193-212) and it should work. Don't put components with props in `ReactDom.render`